# Adding the results of CASE statements

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following Oracle SQL query.  Given a given name and surname, it finds all records with One name and the initial of the other, in either order.  I have created the `score` column to place likely matches at the top of the results set.

```
SELECT
  surname,
  givenname,
  (CASE WHEN surname = 'Smith' THEN 2 ELSE 0)
    + (CASE WHEN givenname = 'John' THEN 1 ELSE 0)
    AS score
FROM person
WHERE (surname = 'Smith' AND givenname LIKE 'J%')
  OR  (surname LIKE 'S%' AND givenname = 'John')
  OR  (surname = 'John' AND givenname LIKE 'S%')
  OR  (surname LIKE 'J%' AND givenname = 'Smith')
ORDER BY
  score DESC,
  surname ASC,
  givenname ASC;
```

The problem is the `score` is giving an error at the location of the `+`.  The IDE reports:

> Syntax error, expected:
>   /
>   *
>   |

And execution reports:

> SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword

What am I doing wrong?  Is there a better way to calculate the score?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the `END` on your `CASE` statements:

```
SELECT
  surname,
  givenname,
  (CASE WHEN surname = 'Smith' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END)  -- < add END
    + (CASE WHEN givenname = 'John' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  -- < add END
    AS score
FROM person
WHERE (surname = 'Smith' AND givenname LIKE 'J%')
  OR  (surname LIKE 'S%' AND givenname = 'John')
  OR  (surname = 'John' AND givenname LIKE 'S%')
  OR  (surname LIKE 'J%' AND givenname = 'Smith')
ORDER BY
  score DESC,
  surname ASC,
  givenname ASC;
```

Comment: Bah!  The one thing it didn't suggest was missing from my statement.  Thanks!