# Add 2 SUM CASE statements as a column update in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update, case

I think I have this almost figured out but after 50+ Google searches, I ask this:  How can I add a column to a db that is essentially a sumif function?  I've seen many related questions as simple Select statements for just looking at the table in a mini table but I was hoping to actually **add a column** that would show these totals.  I'm taking this and then pulling the data into R for further analysis.

In Excel it works like so with [ ] denoting columns of a table. It is split into 2 areas via the Serial #.  The first 6 digits of the serial indicate the "parent" and the later half indicate the "child".  One parent can have multiple children, as seen with BSA101 below.  What I'm trying to do is sum all the costs that went into making the child (parent + child costs).  So the total parent costs, get allocated to both children below.

"Packing" is the last step so this is where I'd want the totals to end up so there are no duplicates.

**Example**

`=IF(LEN([serial])>6,IF([process]="Packing",SUMIF([serial],[@serial],[process_cost])+SUMIF([serial],LEFT([@serial],6),[process_cost]),""),"")`

```
serial  process process_cost    total_child_cost
BSA101A33   Packing  10         160 
BSA101A34   Packing  10         195 
BSA101      Cast     50         ""
BSA101      Mold     30         ""
BSA101      Mold     30         ""
BSA101A33   Finish   15         ""
BSA101A34   Finish   25         ""
BSA101A33   Polish   25         ""
BSA101A34   Polish   50         ""
```

^desired table result above

MySQL attempt:This post helped me  [Adding Case Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675933/adding-the-results-of-case-statements)

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0e58

Here I've added a column in `data` called `total_cost`.  Right now I'm getting an "Invalid use of group function" error which after researching, talks about a `HAVING` clause but not sure where to place it.

```
UPDATE data
    SET total__child_cost = 
        (CASE WHEN length(serial) > 6
                    AND process = 'Packing'
                        THEN
                            IF(serial = serial, sum(process_cost),0) END)
                            +
                            (CASE WHEN left(serial,6) = serial
                                THEN sum(process_cost)
                            END)
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Sorry about, I keep forgetting SQL Fiddle when I ask these - bookmarked!  Will add the example here shortly.

Comment: The fiddle is the least important part of it.

Comment: I think I met the requirements in your post, is there anything else I can add?  I'm being completely honest, as I want to make sure I do this right.

Comment: You're missing the desired result - or maybe I just don't understand it

Comment: Sorry about that: the desired result is the table I created above with the "160" and "195" in the top right of the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being the solution.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `getParent1`(inSerialn Varchar(20)) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
    Declare parent varchar(20); 
    Declare result int; 
    set parent = left(inSerialn, 6);
    set result = (Select sum(process_cost) From mfng.data where serialn = parent);
    return result;
END //

 DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `getChild1`(inSerialn Varchar(20)) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
    Declare result int; 
    set result = (Select sum(process_cost) FROM mfng.data where serialn = inSerialn);
    return result;
END//

UPDATE mfng.data set total_child_cost = 
(case when length(serialn) > 6 AND pdn_process = 'Packing'
THEN 
getChild1(serialn) + getParent1(serialn)
ELSE 
0 END);
//
```